# wp_set_script_translations returns false

Tags: javascript, wordpress, internationalization, wordpress-gutenberg

**wp_set_script_translations()** I am using this function for translating string from javascript file but it always returns false. Please check below for details:

**I have enqueued assets**

```
wp_register_script( 'test-js', tutor()->url . 'assets/js/test.js', array( 'jquery', 'wp-i18n'), time(), true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'test-js');
```

**In jQuery file:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    'use strict';
    /**
     * translate support 
     * @since 
    */
    const { __ } = wp.i18n;
    var text =  __('Please select an option to answer', 'text-domain');
    console.log(text); //showing default lang , translate is not working
})
```

**Loaded text domain**

```
add_action( 'init', 'language_load');
function language_load() {
    /**
     * script translation support added
     * @since 
    */
    
    var_dump(wp_set_script_translations( 'test-js', 'text-domain', plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'languages'));//returns false  
//already tried wp_set_script_translations( 'test-js', 'text-domain', plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'/languages/')

//already tried wp_set_script_translations( 'test-js', 'text-domain', plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'languages/')   

}
```

**Note:** POT file has created by using WP CLI, PO & JSON file has also created by using WP CLI. Since wp_set_script_translations() return false translate not working.

Answer (score 0):

After debugging I found answer myself, sharing here if it could help someone:
Basically init hook runs before wp_enqueue_scripts that is why it could not find handled script with text domain attached to.
In this case I have used wp_enqueue_scripts hook with lower priority. Like below:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'load_scripts'));

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'load_text_domain'),100);

function tutor_script_text_domain() {
    wp_set_script_translations( 
         'test-js',
         'text-domain',
         plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) .'languages' );
}
```